# Why does pip not have pylauncher support?

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

In the table on the pip vs easy_install page it states that pip does not support pylauncher and easy_install does install pylauncher.

Resource: https://packaging.python.org/discussions/pip-vs-easy-install/

Why does pip not support pylauncher (or vice-versa)?

Comment: That's a rather broad topic… probably because nobody deemed it necessary enough to include it yet.

Comment: or that pylauncher is (seems?) dead (last commit in 2013)